# Race detector runtime error

Tags: go

The golang race detector is crashing/not running. Error output is:

```
$ go test -race
# testmain
runtime.RaceErrors: relocation target __tsan_report_count not defined
runtime.RaceErrors: undefined: "__tsan_report_count"
FAIL    raft/vendor/raft/connectionManager [build failed]
```

go is newly installed 1.8 from Ubuntu repository.
Go race runtime was reinstalled from apt.

go env:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="~/Source/Go--Dev/bin"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="~/Source/Go--Dev"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.8"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.8/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build905991578=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Install Go from the official release.

Comment: Indeed installing from official does work... I'm still curious as to why the installed version borked, but I guess it serves me right for trying to take the easy way out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. In my case, I was on a new machine and simply did not have `gcc` installed yet. After `sudo apt install gcc` everything worked fine.